# filtering data frame based on column (item_id) value which have all digits?

Tags: r, dataframe, pattern-matching

following is a sample data frame in R -

```
date                  item_id           price
2010-09-15            0034              4546
2010-09-15            ABXC              4325
2010-09-15            12AB              3545
2010-09-15            ZF9C              4354
2010-09-15            Z923              7854
2010-09-15            923F              780
```

desired output-

```
date                  item_id           price
2010-09-15            ABXC              4325
2010-09-15            12AB              3545
2010-09-15            ZF9C              4354
2010-09-15            Z923              7854
2010-09-15            923F              780
```

i tried so far -

```
outlier_seq<-c('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')
df1<-sample_df[!grepl(paste(outlier_seq, collapse = "|"), sample$item_id),]
```

but this is removing all the item_id consists number. instead of that just I want to filter out those records, whose item_id consist of all number. any help on this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or we can use `tidyverse`, by matching patterns that start (`^`) with one or more non-numeric (`[^0-9]+`) character with `str_detect` to return a logical vector to `filter` the rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
mydf %>% 
    filter(str_detect(item_id, "^[^0-9]+"))
#        date item_id price
#1 2010-09-15    ABXC  4325
#2 2010-09-15    ZF9C  4354
#3 2010-09-15  ZF9C23  7854
```

#### Update

For the updated question in OP's post, we can look for pattern that have one or more numbers (`[0-9]+`) from start (`^`) to end (`$`) of string, negate (`!`) the logical vector to reverse the `TRUE/FALSE` to `FALSE/TRUE` and `filter`

```
mydf %>%
       filter(!str_detect(item_id, "^[0-9]+$"))
#        date item_id price
#1 2010-09-15    ABXC  4325
#2 2010-09-15    12AB  3545
#3 2010-09-15    ZF9C  4354
#4 2010-09-15  ZF9C23  7854
```

#### Update2

Based on OP's concern that it is filtering out "07R2", tested it by adding another row with that value

```
mydf %>% 
     filter(!str_detect(item_id, "^[0-9]+$"))
 #        date item_id price
 #1 2010-09-15    ABXC  4325
 #2 2010-09-15    12AB  3545
 #3 2010-09-15    ZF9C  4354
 #4 2010-09-15  ZF9C23  7854
 #5 2010-09-15    07R2  7934
```

#### Update3

Based on the new dataset by OP

```
mydf %>% 
     filter(!str_detect(item_id, "^[0-9]+$"))
#        date item_id price
#1 2010-09-15    ABXC  4325
#2 2010-09-15    12AB  3545
#3 2010-09-15    ZF9C  4354
#4 2010-09-15    Z923  7854
#5 2010-09-15    923F   780
```

Even if the column is `factor` it works

```
mydf %>%
      filter(!str_detect(factor(item_id), "^[0-9]+$"))
#        date item_id price
#1 2010-09-15    ABXC  4325
#2 2010-09-15    12AB  3545
#3 2010-09-15    ZF9C  4354
#4 2010-09-15    Z923  7854
#5 2010-09-15    923F   780
```

#### data

```
#data from last update
mydf <- structure(list(date = c("2010-09-15", "2010-09-15", "2010-09-15", 
"2010-09-15", "2010-09-15", "2010-09-15"), item_id = c("0034", 
"ABXC", "12AB", "ZF9C", "Z923", "923F"), price = c(4546L, 4325L, 
3545L, 4354L, 7854L, 780L)), .Names = c("date", "item_id", "price"
 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: ur answer is absolutely correct no doubt. but I made changes in the posted question, for pattern matching I saw the regular expression but not find related to above use case. take a look once, any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: i got following error- could not find function "str_detect"

Comment: @andy Updated with the `library`.

Comment: still it filter out some of column values which has alphabet in item_id for ex-"07R2". i want to filter out those records only whose item_id consists of all digits. i am having 400000 no of records.

Comment: @andy Could you please update your question with all the patterns

Comment: @andy It is not filtering it out `!str_detect("07R2", "^[0-9]+$")
[1] TRUE`

Comment: @andy I get the expected output based on your new data.  Updated again

Comment: @andy You can also check whether there are leading/lagging spaces etc or the class of the columns as I am not able to reproduce the problem

Comment: class is of factor for item_id. I just want to filter out those records whose item_id values are all digit like 0012,003,0045,etc and typeof(item_id) is showing integer.

Comment: @andy Even if it is a `factor`, it should work.  Anyway, my solution works for all the examples you provided.

Comment: thanks a lot for patience help. I will try to follow yours recommendation.

Comment: @andy Can you do one thing.  Get the example data using `dput` i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(mydf)))` then we will know what the problem is

Comment: I did and it shows item_id of factor type. but still it filter out some records for item_id "07R1","07R2" "06H6","ZH08"etc

Comment: @andy It is not happening on my side `!str_detect(c("07R1","07R2", "06H6","ZH08"),  "^[0-9]+$")#
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE`

Comment: thanks a lot bro. I will try to figure out where is the problem, bcoz for some records still getting FALSE value.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are starting with:

```
mydf <- structure(list(date = c("2010-09-15", "2010-09-15", "2010-09-15", 
    "2010-09-15", "2010-09-15"), item_id = c("0034", "ABXC", "12AB", 
    "ZF9C", "ZF9C23"), price = c(4546L, 4325L, 3545L, 4354L, 7854L
    )), .Names = c("date", "item_id", "price"), row.names = c(NA, 
    5L), class = "data.frame")
```

You should be able to just do:

```
mydf[!grepl("^[0-9]", mydf$item_id), ]
##         date item_id price
## 2 2010-09-15    ABXC  4325
## 4 2010-09-15    ZF9C  4354
## 5 2010-09-15  ZF9C23  7854
```

Comment: I made changes in the posted question, for pattern matching I saw the regular expression but not find related to above use case. take a look once, any help or suggestion is appreciated.